# Temporary Table and Set Variables mysql --- UPDATES

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, backend

I want to both create a temporary table and utilize a variable. I have consulted the documentation and I believe the syntax is correct but putting them together is giving me an error.

My goal is to create a date variable that is always 1 year before `now()` and will populate my temporary table with one month increment rows until the present moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @start_date = DATEADD(year, -1 ,GETDATE())\n\n  WHILE @start_date < GETD' at line 4"
```

Here is my SQL statement.

```
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE helper(
          date datetime not null
          );

        SET @start_date = DATEADD(year, -1 ,GETDATE())

        WHILE @start_date < GETDATE()
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO helper VALUES (@start_date)
          SELECT @start_date = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @start_date)
        
        END
```

update 1

with this code I am still receiving a syntax error

```
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE helper(
          date datetime not null
        );
          
        insert into helper (date)
          with recursive cte as (
            select curdate() - interval 12 month as date
            union all
            select date + interval 1 month
            from cte
            where date < curdate()
          )
          select date from cte;

          select * from helper;
```

error

```
 "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into helper (date)\n          with recursive cte as (\n            select c' at line 4",
```

UPDATE 2

I have changed the syntax to this. I am still getting errors but it seems to be closer to mySql 5.7

```
 `
          CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE helper(
            date datetime not null
          );

          CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
          BEGIN
          DECLARE date datetime DEFAULT SUBDATE(curdate(), interval 12 month);
            WHILE date < curDate() DO
              INSERT INTO helper VALUES(date);
              SET date = date + interval 1 month;
            END WHILE;
          END;
          DELIMITER;

          CALL dowhile()

          SELECT date_format(log.entry_stamp, '%Y-%M') AS 'date', COUNT(log.element_id) as count FROM dm_log log
          INNER JOIN dm_element el
          ON el.element_id = log.element_id
          WHERE ? = el.dm_id
          LEFT OUTER JOIN helper h
          ON h.date = log.date
          GROUP BY date
          ORDER BY date;

          DROP TEMPORARY TABLE helper; 
             `
```

Error

```
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()\n          BEGIN\n          DECLARE date datetime DEFAU' at line 4",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE instead of a `WHILE` loop:

```
insert into helper (date)
    with recursive cte as (
          select curdate() - interval 12 month as date
          union all
          select date + interval 1 month
          from cte
          where date < curdate()
         )
    select date from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c161a031904d2ea2583614f28580762) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that MySQL does not use `getdate()`.  And doesn't support `while` loops outside of programming blocks.  And doesn't have a three-argument form of `dateadd()`.  It looks like you are confusing MySQL with SQL Server.

In earlier versions, you'll probably need to list the values explictly:

```
insert into helper (date)
    select curdate() union all
    select curdate() - interval 1 month union all
    . . .;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my question with your provided code as I am still getting a syntax error with the new code. Though I see that yours works with dbfiddle.

Comment: @helper12345 . . . What version of MySQL are you using?  Recursive CTEs are available since version 8.0.

Comment: If I were to use syntax which would work with the previous version, is there one that would do the same thing?

Comment: I was wrong, it's 5.7. Is there an anologous syntax for 5.7?